# CodedUI v11 multi-browser support

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to run Codedui tests in chrome. Here is the code i'm using:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://msdn.com"));
```

But i'm getting exception: "The browser chrome is currently not supported".
I have VS2012 Ultimate and 'Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing' installed.

Am I doing something wrong or is there smthing i need to check?

Comment: are you on VS2012 update 1?

Answer (score 2):

I believe I am getting a similar issue regarding cross browser and CodedUi tests. I think it is due to compatibility problems and the fact that VS2012 CodedUi can only run in IE from what I have read. Hopefully this link might help you, or at least give you a starting point towards a solution. Sorry I couldn't be of further help.

[CodedUI Cross Browser Plugin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests.aspx?ocid=soc-n-eg-elite--MRadwan)

Answer (score 1):

This got me started.  After I installed and made some tweaks to some test cases I was able to run coded ui tests on Chrome.

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=267598

Answer (score 1):

You should install VS2012 update 1 or greater to use this functional